# Django users can't login after I create an account but admin can and i didnt create any registration form by only manually can add users

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've created a login page as a homepage and only by adding manually in Django administration can create a user. I didn't create a registration form and message error else statement in home viwes.py is working on the admin panel. If I login by user, I get CSRF token error

homepage
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from loginapp.models import Register
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login , logout

def home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
   if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      return render(request, "home.html")
   else:
        messages.error(request, "Bad Creds!!")
        return redirect('/')    

 return render(request, "home.html")
```

login page views.py

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, "index.html")
```

login page name as index.html

```
<form id="stripe-login" method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">  
  {% csrf_token %}           
 <div class="trick" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
   <input type="text" name="username" required>
   <label for="email">Username</label>
 </div>
 <div class=" trick" style="padding-bottom:10px;">                
   <input type="password" name="password" required>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
 </div>
 
 <div class="field"  style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-top: 10px;">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue">
 </div>
 <div class="reset-pass" style="padding-top: 20px;">
   <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
 </div>
 <div class="footer-link text-light" style="padding-top:10px;">
   <span>
     Don't have an account?
     <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">
       Request for a new account
     </a>
   </span>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: if this is still relevant, I assume the problem is in the html template, namely `for` attribute in the `label` tag of username should point to `username` not `email`

Answer (score 0):

for creating user you must use
User.objects.create_user() method
Ex: User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).